# How do I use property bag in Sharepoint designer Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, property-bag

Is it possible to store and retrieve values from property bags in sharepoint designer workflows.

Thanks 
Swayam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We are not able to access site property bag values with all default
>   workflow actions in SharePoint Designer. But you may consider
>   following workaround.
>
> 1.Export the properties to a list on the same web site with custom code, so that we can access the properties by accessing the data from
>   a list.
>
> 2.Create a custom workflow activity. Refer to this blog to create a custom workflow activity.
>
> http://msmvps.com/blogs/sundar_narasiman/archive/2010/12/26/develop-custom-workflow-activity-for-sharepoint-2010-workflow.aspx
>
> 3.Create a Visual Studio workflow instead. Create a Sequential workflow with Visual Studio.
>
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg265727(v=office.14).aspx

[Source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sharepoint/en-US/f568b48a-91c5-49a2-a470-dcd1f829d2a3/how-can-we-bring-the-site-property-bag-values-inside-workflow-in-spd)